# Test for presence of specific object or managed package?

Tags: managed-package, custom-object

I am writing a test class that needs to be instance-agnostic. On some of our instances we have a managed package that affects the outcome of the test, so I need to insert some test data that will be used by that managed package, but I'm worried that if I migrate this test case to instances without that managed package, it will fail when trying to insert this test data for objects that don't exist on that instance.

To make a long question shorter, is there a way to test for the presence or absence of either a specific object or a managed package so I can run this code conditionally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your best approach is probably to use a combination of testing for the presence of the package, and then checking the running user has access in case there are licence restrictions in place.

@user320 answer offers some good suggestions on how to detect a package - if there are record types, they are also a good option in my experience.

If the package exists, I would check that the running user has access to the package with this method on [userinfo](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm#apex_System_UserInfo_isCurrentUserLicensed) so that you know they can write to fields on the package:

```
userinfo.isCurrentUserLicensed('kw');
```

Note - if the namespace does NOT exist, you'll get an exception, so I would so something like this just in case:

```
Boolean bPackage = FALSE;
try{
    bPackage = userinfo.isCurrentUserLicensed('kw');
}
Catch (Exception Ex) {
system.debug(ex);
}
if (bPackage) {
//Insert test data
};
```

Also, you'll need to make sure your data inserts don't explicitly reference any fields in the package directly, or you will create a dependency, but if you use dynamic DML with put statements, you should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

While `Userinfo.isCurrentUserLicensed()` is a good first port of call, I'd humbly recommend detecting the presence of a global Apex class or SObject that you know for sure will be in the package:

```
if (Type.forName('namespace.ClassWithGlobalVisibility') != null) {
    //your test data here
}
```

or

```
if (Type.forName('namespace__SalesforceObject__c') != null) {
    //your test data here
}
```

This is **license-agnostic**; it works even if your customers have the package installed but no license.

Comment: That should work - my only hesitation with recommending that approach was that with user-licensed packages, you might need a licence in order to be able to write to the fields - so depending on the package you are trying to detect, a combination of the two might be prudent!

Comment: Nice observation! Let's join forces, and add that to your answer? @BritishBoyinDC

Comment: I'm relatively new to StackExchange. I’ve marked @BritishBoyinDC’s answer as the correct one, but is there any way for me to give @user320 some credit for this answer, too?